# Renaming executable to game.exe causes 15 second delay when running -- STRANGE issue

Tags: c++, windows, sdl

This shakes my understanding of computers and operating systems on a level that makes me very uneasy. I have just spent about an hour entering different iterations of compile commands to `g++` and in my exasperation I renamed the executable which kept having the delay from `game.exe` to `gameg.exe` and all of a sudden the problem vanished.

Here's some more background: I was noticing recently that when I ran my Eclipse unit test build, when I start with an SDL enabled test it would open the SDL window and freeze for about 20 seconds before being able to get the test started. On subsequent tests (which call `SDL_Quit()` and re-initialize SDL as part of the test process) this delay is not present. Now I have ascertained that ONLY when the executable is named exactly "game.exe" does this happen! I rename it to any other filename and it goes along running tests happily, initializing the SDL system within a second like it usually does. I had assumed before that there must be some kind of bug that was causing my Eclipse build to have this behavior which wasn't present in the makefile build, but it turns out if I take the eclipse build and rename its executable (the project folder it's in is called `game` hence `game.exe`) it doesn't exhibit the behavior.

Likewise I take my makefile build (whose filename is `entropy_unittest_disp.exe` fyi) and rename it to `game.exe` and it begins to do this. I rename it to `game` and it also does it (I am running from mingw's bash.. when not with `.exe` extension, explorer doesn't know it's an executable). However I changed it to `game.exx` and it worked normally.

WHAT IS THIS BLACK MAGIC? Why should a program function differently depending on its filename??? I do query argv[0] and i actually do it to print to console its value (for debug purposes) but unsurprisingly it just prints the program and its path. No logic is ever performed on it in my program.

I tried to run GDB to find out where it is freezing but once I press Ctrl+C GDB simply exits.

does anybody have any idea what this might be caused by? A virus?

edit: I downloaded this demo from this site: http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics/

extracted it, renamed the file to game.exe, and yup, same thing happens. WHAT IS THIS? I'm going to try running dependency walker next to see if something's trying to hook into it.

Comment: What version of Windows?  Have you tried running with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see if something jumps out at you?  Recent version of Windows (Vista and 7, I believe) sometimes does treat executables differently if they have special filenames, e.g. setup programs, but AFAIK "game.exe" is not one of those special filenames.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate... I tried Process Monitor, it is really kind of amazing that it's able to capture everything happening. But it's generating 100 to 1000 events per second. I guess I can try to kill as many background processes as possible before attempting to sort things out. Thanks for showing me the tool, though.

Comment: Add game.exe as an inclusive filter so you won't have background events in your log. (Filter dialog has a funnel icon and also appears at startup)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you have either a AMD (ATI) or Nvidia graphics card with their official drivers.

Chances are, game.exe is the executable name for an actual game released and your drivers are running special optimizations for the "game" or loading the Crossfire or SLI profiles for this game. A quick Google search seems to tell me that Resident Evil 4 calls their executable "game.exe."

I recommend taking a look at this link for further details as to what may be happening:

http://www.kn00tcn.net/site/ati-catalyst-profiles/

Comment: I think the answer is definitely related to this. Process Manager helped me get some clues (or rather, about five thousand of them). There are a ton of registry queries just like everything else but it seems to enter a loop of creating and reading files in `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA\...` and then there is a long string of attempts to create a file called `ra2.exe` in the same dir as my game executable. I google it and come up with this: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=201944 I guess they never fixed the issue. This is what we call software bloat, folks.

Comment: BTW, I'm curious... What sort of mechanism do they use to do this sort of thing? I take it that there isn't much that you can't do once you start messing around in the OS with drivers?

Answer (score 2):

not sure how to reply to steven's comment on the top answer, but regarding driver profiles, it's just a basic brute force check of .exe filenames

some games are guaranteed to be in a specific sub folder, so the driver looks for *where* the exe is located, such as '\team fortress 2\hl2.exe'

but since most games let you pick what folder name you're installing to, & a lot of the time the exe is in that same root folder, the drivers have no choice but to blindly assume gameX.exe is going to be gameX

a nice 'side effect' of this is you can force other game profiles on any game for troubleshooting purposes, or to try to enable CF/SLI scaling

so always try to make sure that your executable has an original name to know that the gfx driver isnt attempting to run 'optimizations' made exclusively for other games

Answer (score 1):

Could this be due to Anti virus software running on your OS? Certain files are commonly used in Virus "Game.exe" could be one of them and hence additional care from OS / AV to ensure that it is safe

Answer (score 1):

Test it in clean windows, without any extra software installation, if it work fine, then maybe you have some protection software like Anti-virus or sandbox , ... , if you have any of this software disable them, and test again

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if game.exe is listed in the Image File Execution Options registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`. It can be used to launch a particular program as a debugger for an application with a particular name. ([More info on Image File Execution Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

An EXE will behave differently based on its name due to AppCompat Shimming. Check the loaded module list and see if there are a bunch of DLLs that start with "ac" loaded into your app.